# Ruby on Rails 4 send_data safari appends .html

Tags: macos, ruby-on-rails-4, safari

I have quite annoying problem.

When using **Safari** on **Mac OS X** everything it downloads from web page, it appends **.html**

What is really strange, that if Safari is used in any other OS (Ubuntu/OpenSuse/Windows) it works like intended.
Also if I use any other browser on Mac OS X it is ok as well.

Originally I call method from view, but result is the same if I call directly from controller.

**Controller:**

```
      def download_data
        object = Object.generated_to_csv

        send_data(object, type: 'text/csv; charset=utf-8; header=present', filename: 'some_file.csv', disposition: 'attachment')
      end
```

So I expect Safari to download me a file having *some_file.csv* name but I get *some_file.csv.html*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found code which overrides everything:

```
headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

Which solves my problem if used correctly.